# Set column width for pandas print out

Tags: python, pandas

given data as

```
In [403]: data=pd.DataFrame(
     ...: {
     ...: 'A':['hello there', 1],
     ...: 'B':['something', 44],
     ...: })

In [404]: data
Out[404]:
             A          B
0  hello there  something
1            1         44
```

I would like to be able to do something along the lines of

```
pd.set_output_width(4)
```

Which would result in the terminal output of the previous dataframe being alongt the 
lines of

```
In [404]: data
Out[404]:
    A      B
0  hell  some
1   1     44
```

Answer (score 2):

I test check display to `4`, but it will be truncated with an ellipsis for length `4+`:

```
with pd.option_context('display.max_colwidth', 3):
    print (data)
             A          B
0  hello there  something
1   1           44
```

---

```
with pd.option_context('display.max_colwidth', 4):
    print (data)
     A    B
0  ...  ...
1    1   44
```

---

```
with pd.option_context('display.max_colwidth', 5):
    print (data)
      A     B
0  h...  s...
1     1    44
```

---

```
with pd.option_context('display.max_colwidth', 6):
    print (data)
       A      B
0  he...  so...
1      1     44
```

---

```
with pd.option_context('display.max_colwidth', 8):
    print (data)
         A        B
0  hell...  some...
1        1       44
```

I think close, what you need is slicing - with `apply` for all columns slicing:

```
print (data.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str[:4]))
      A     B
0  hell  some
1     1    44
```

Or with `applymap` for elementwise slicing:

```
print (data.astype(str).applymap(lambda x: x[:4]))
      A     B
0  hell  some
1     1    44
```

Comment: this makes sense - thank you. I have a question, why would one of `applymap` or `apply` be used over the other in this scenario ? It seems that `apply` is column/row whereas `applymap` is element wise, yet in this context they both (seem to) do the same thing

Comment: @baxx - Yes, you are right. Obviously `applymap` is rarest used, because elementwise operation are slowiest like column/row opearations.

Comment: would be interesting to see the performance too (if you can add them) , I have a feeling that since `apply` also has a `str` accessor in this case ,which is also slow, `applymap` can be actually faster combined. Not tested though. :)

Comment: @anky_91 - tested for 20 columns, 20000rows - by `data = pd.concat([data] * 10, axis=1, ignore_index=True)
data = pd.concat([data] * 10000, ignore_index=True)` and get `%timeit (data.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str[:4]))
217 ms ± 4.08 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit (data.astype(str).applymap(lambda x: x[:4]))
199 ms ± 10.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)`

Comment: It is difference only 18ms, not sure if no much or not ;)

Comment: @jezrael thank you yes, its close, but i am glad i thought correctly :P